# iOS upload file to service with xmlHttpRequest (cordova platform)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a xlsx file in document directory of iphone to a service.

1. I am using xmlHttpRequest to load file from directory as arraybuffer
2. Converting the array buffer as Uint8Array
3. Create a formData object and append the Uint8Array array object to it
4. Send a ajax post request to upload service

When I do this, I get response as Status code 414 and error message as Unsupported media type. I believe this is due to the file that I am uploading and it is not in proper format as required.

Can any help me in identifying where I am going wrong or is there any alternative approach for doing same?

```
var serverUrl = "http://3.1.177.75/ExcelIO/xsapi/import/";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var classRoot = this;
var xlsxFile = 'points to document directory of iphone where xlsx file is present';
request.open("GET", xlsxFile, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = function(e) {
    var arraybuffer = request.response;
    var filedata = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("ExcelOpenFlags", excelOpenFlags);
    formData.append("file", filedata);
    $.ajax({
           url: serverUrl,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function completeHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           if (successCallback) {
           alert("success");
           }
           },
           error: function errorHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error "+JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + " -- "+errorThrown);
           },
           data: formData,  
           cache: false,  
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           headers: {  
           "Accept": "application/json"
           }
           });
};
request.send();
```

Comment: Is the iPhone sending with Content-Type: application/json header?

Comment: @LeeMeador, Request MIME type is multipart/form-data

Comment: why don't you send it with phonegap's filetransfer api?